# debug mode on samsung galaxy Android 4.3

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

Where is debug-mode customization in new OS version?
In old version there was simple menu. Now I can't find. Please, help.

Comment: I searched for it and it was the first result: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable Developer Options. Go to **Settings > Device Info** and tap on **Build Number** multiple times (fast)

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of weird.. But since you only have to do this once, I think the drawback for developers is not too bad.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of movies on Youtube for these issues

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KWYFer-cxCU

Comment: Thanks. They do not think about developers.